# Are function declarations with abstract class types ill-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950540/forcing-clang-to-generate-compilation-error-on-this-snippet-of-c-code), I had a look around the standard. There is a note in [[class.abstract]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#abstract-3)

> [Note: An abstract class type cannot be used as a parameter or return type of a function being defined ([dcl.fct]) or called ([expr.call]), except as specified in [dcl.type.simple]. [...]

For definitions [[dcl.fct.def.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct.def.general-2)

> The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be a (possibly cv-qualified) class type that is incomplete or abstract within the function body unless the function is deleted ([dcl.fct.def.delete]).

But I couldn't find anything about declarations, by which I can only conclude there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The function declaration has to match the function definition, doesn't it? So if it's not allowed in the definition, how can you use it in a declaration?

Comment: @Barmar You could declare and never define the function.

Comment: And never call it, either? What's the point of it?

Comment: @Barmar Metaprogramming comes to mind. And equally importantly, is there a gcc bug.

Comment: http://wg21.link/P0929, merged in https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2149

Comment: @Barmar Pre C++11 you declared copy ctor private and never defined it to make it practically deleted.

Comment: @PasserBy - The question you linked to has an answer which explains (with references to the standard) that declaring a function for which a parameter or return type is an abstract class is ill-formed (except in particular cases).

Comment: @Peter The confusion arises due to P0929. And me being a slow writer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [P0929](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0929r2.html). Prior to C++20, function declarations are also ill-formed, but it lead to surprising semantics. Suppose

```
struct S;

S foo();  // 1

struct S { virtual void bar() = 0; };  // 2
```

At `1`, the function is well-formed, yet `2` retroactively made it ill-formed. This is highly unintuitive, and so was changed.

Comment: _Prior to C++20_ Hm. IDK if it is correct to say this if P0929 says _It is recommended to treat this as a Defect Report against earlier versions of C++_ (Don't know if this was actually accepted as DR)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I was also mightily confused about that as well, a quick search yielded nothing so I decided to omit it.

Comment: Note that [P0636R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0636r3.html) explicitly refers to P0929R2 as to be considered a defect in C++17: _"The following papers contain (not exclusively) wording changes that do not appear in the published International Standard, but that are considered defects in C++17: ... P0929R2 ..."_.